# Are docker compose and spring boot 3 not currently compatible?

Tags: docker-compose

I'm learning about docker and I wanted to try run my application in a container. My application currently has a local mysql database. After doing some research I found docker compose can create two containers (one for the database and one for the application) and they can connect to each other. I wanted to give this a try but the application fails to run. I get a NPE saying "Cannot invoke "org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCliInspectResponse.hostConfig()" because "inspectResponse" is null"

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.1)

2024-02-07T14:26:28.690Z  INFO 26232 --- [           main] com.sparta.tma.TmaApplication            : Starting TmaApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 26232 (C:\Users\jades\OneDrive\Documents\Udemy\Docker\first try with tma\target\classes started by jades in C:\Users\jades\OneDrive\Documents\Udemy\Docker\first try with tma)
2024-02-07T14:26:28.694Z  INFO 26232 --- [           main] com.sparta.tma.TmaApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-02-07T14:26:28.780Z  INFO 26232 --- [           main] .s.b.d.c.l.DockerComposeLifecycleManager : Using Docker Compose file 'C:\Users\jades\OneDrive\Documents\Udemy\Docker\first try with tma\docker-compose.yml'
2024-02-07T14:26:31.475Z ERROR 26232 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCliInspectResponse.hostConfig()" because "inspectResponse" is null
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DefaultConnectionPorts.isHostNetworkMode(DefaultConnectionPorts.java:56) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DefaultConnectionPorts.<init>(DefaultConnectionPorts.java:47) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DefaultRunningService.<init>(DefaultRunningService.java:55) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DefaultDockerCompose.getRunningServices(DefaultDockerCompose.java:83) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeLifecycleManager.start(DockerComposeLifecycleManager.java:120) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeListener.onApplicationEvent(DockerComposeListener.java:53) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeListener.onApplicationEvent(DockerComposeListener.java:35) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.contextLoaded(EventPublishingRunListener.java:98) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$contextLoaded$4(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:72) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.contextLoaded(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:72) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:416) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at com.sparta.tma.TmaApplication.main(TmaApplication.java:19) ~[classes/:na]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my current docker compose file

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.13
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dockerdb
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3307/MYSQL_DATABASE
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
```

I have looked online and found only a few sources but the issue seems to be that it's a bug with docker compose (version 23 I think) not being compatible with spring boot version at that time (around 4/5months ago) I did find a [github repo](https://github.com/gulybyte/sample-todo/issues/23) where it said this bug was fixed with the latest version of docker, which I now have and I am still getting the same error.

I have tried different versions of Spring Boot 3, different versions of Java and the newest version of docker desktop and I'm still receiving the same error.

**Note:** I have also tried a docker compose file with two services, app and db, the one above is just one for the db as per the youtube video.

This is the [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S70HqxGRswA&t=1171s) I was following.

I'm new to docker so if there is a better way to containerise a mysql database and connect it to a containerised java application please do let me know.

-TIA

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve] with code that reproduces the error you're asking about.

Comment: @larsks Thanks for the suggestion, I did that and it works. Not sure if there is was a dependency causing the issue or just something in my project entirely. Thanks for the tip!